# Exported function discovery with LibraryFunction

Tags: external-calls, mac-os-x, system, librarylink, unix

Many internal calls boil down to invocations like

```
LibraryFunction["path/to/library", "funcName" , ...]
```

I'm on a mac, so I can use the `nm` command in the terminal to reveal the list of available functions.  Take, for instance, the ZMQ library for network calls:

```
lib = "/Applications/Mathematica.app/Contents/SystemFiles/Links/ZeroMQLink/LibraryResources/MacOSX-x86-64/libzeromqlink.dylib";
RunProcess[{"nm","-gU",lib}, "StandardOutput"]

(*Out[1] = *)
00000000000060d0 T _BindZMQSocket
00000000000054f0 T _CloseZMQContext
000000000001f7e0 T _Close_SocketObject
...
000000000002a158 S _wrisockets_IPPROTO_UDP
000000000002a160 S _wrisockets_SOCK_DGRAM
000000000002a15c S _wrisockets_SOCK_STREAM
```

## Question

Is there a WL function for exploring library contents instead of `RunProcess` and explicitly mentioning `nm` or other system details?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I believe the answer is no, there is not. If you want to load a function from a library using LibraryFunctionLoad or ForeignFunctionLoad, you need to already know the name. For functions gotten by LibraryFunctionLoad, at least, you can use LibraryFunctionInformation to get the signature; for those gotten by ForeignFunctionLoad you also need to know the signature.

If you're curious, you can always use GeneralUtilities`PrintDefinitions to see the top-level implementation of a built-in function, if one exists. If instead a built-in invokes hidden downcode, this function will tell you as well.

Comment: I also realized that the `.wl` files in `$InstallationDirectory<>"/SystemFiles/Links/*"` are very readable as examples of library function usage.  Perhaps that's what PrintDefinitions uses...